# How do I use textcolor inside discretionary?

Tags: color, listings, line-breaking, discretionary

I'm trying to get long inline code to wrap at points that I specify with `\-`. I've got it working almost perfectly with this:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty,parskip]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=6in,margin=2cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\sloppy

\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\relscale{0.9}\ttfamily\color{red},keywordstyle=\color{red},stringstyle=\color{red},keepspaces=true,breaklines=true,literate={\\\-}{}{0\discretionary{\textrm{-}}{}{}}]}

\begin{document}

Here is a paragraph with some inline code. \code{Really\-Long\-Name\-First\-Second\-Third\-Fourth\-Fifth}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My last remaining goal is to have the hyphen appear black rather than red, so it appears distinct from the code. I thought I'd just be able to use `textcolor` like this:

```
\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\relscale{0.9}\ttfamily\color{red},keywordstyle=\color{red},stringstyle=\color{red},keepspaces=true,breaklines=true,literate={\\\-}{}{0\discretionary{\textcolor{black}{\textrm{-}}}{}{}}]}
```

However, this gives me:

```
Improper discretionary list
```

I've tried various things, like wrapping the entire `discretionary` piece in `{}`, but nothing I've tried has worked.

How can I make the hyphen black?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using `\textcolor` inside a discretionary, you can use it around the discretionary:

```
\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\relscale{0.9}\ttfamily\color{red},keywordstyle=\color{red},stringstyle=\color{red},keepspaces=true,breaklines=true,literate={\\\-}{}{0\textcolor{black}{\rmfamily\discretionary{-}{}{}}}]}
```

Are you aware of the `\lstset` macro?
Instead of using your `\code`, you can write

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\relscale{0.9}\ttfamily\color{red},keywordstyle=\color{red},stringstyle=\color{red},keepspaces=true,breaklines=true,literate={\\\-}{}{0\textcolor{black}{\rmfamily\discretionary{-}{}{}}}}
```

in your preamble. Then `\lstinline` always uses the options.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I'm at the point where I don't even question why one way works when another doesn't now. Regarding using `lstset` and `lstinline`, I just find `\code` reads (and writes) far nicer.

Comment: For the question why: In `\discretionary` only characters, boxes and kerns are allowed, but `\textcolor` inserts a whatsit.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger whether I was sure or not doesn't really matter, but certainly I was wrong:-)  I'll clean up the comments here and fix my answer, thanks (who implemented `\textcolor` I wonder....)

Answer (score 6):

`\textcolor` colour whatsits to change the colour which are not allowed in a discretionary, however you can have boxes so you just need to put the content of each field in an `\hbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\discretionary
{\hbox{\textcolor{red}{AAA}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{BBB}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{green}{CCC}}}%
bbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\discretionary
{\hbox{\textcolor{red}{AAA}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{BBB}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{green}{CCC}}}%
bbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\discretionary
{\hbox{\textcolor{red}{AAA}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{BBB}}}{\hbox{\textcolor{green}{CCC}}}%
bbbbb
\end{document}
```